# Solve for (x) $x^2 - 2x <\sin^{-1}(\sin 2)$?

Tags: inverse-function

I had tried but not able to get the solution help please
I am getting an inequality

> $x$^2-2$x$+2-π <0

And unable to factories

Comment: Do you mean $x^2-2x<\sin^{-1}(\sin 2)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  edit my question please I am new in this platform and don't know how to write expression perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{2}-2x$ < $sin^{-1}(sin(2))$ => $x^{2}-2x$ < $\pi-2$ =>$\frac{(x-1)^{2}}{\pi-1}$<1 then from the inequality we can deduce the solution as follows $1-\sqrt{\pi-1}<x<1+\sqrt{\pi-1}$